# How to get Scala imports working in IntelliJ IDEA with the Play framework?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm using the Scala plugin for IDEA and normally, it works (almost) perfectly.

However, it seems to have problem with the import statements for the Play framework: I often get the error "Cannot resolve symbol x". Now that doesn't stop the program from working, but it makes autocompletion completely useless.

Example: `import org.scalatest.junit._`

I already added `/opt/play/framework/src` and `/opt/play/framework/play-1.2.2RC2.jar` to classes and sources of my project. (using "Project Structure")

Any ideas on how to solve this? Or is this simply a bug?

(I am using Scala 2.9.0.1, IDEA 10.5 and Scala Plugin 0.4.1084)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add `tmp/generated` to your sources as well. Eclipse also has this issue, since the Play Framework generate the source files from the templates. See [Errors in Eclipse for Scala project generated by Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177851/errors-in-eclipse-for-scala-project-generated-by-play-framework).

Comment: I did that, but I still get the same errors. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: ok, I found out how to fix it: I needed to add  “scala-library” to my. module dependencies: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2010/09/02/project-configuration-explained/